# Where are logs for Daemons of my ruby script

Tags: ruby, daemons, ruby-daemons

I have demamonized my ruby script like this

```
Daemons.run('script/meeting_receiver.rb')
```

basically i am using gem https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons.

And i have used puts statements in my ruby code. So i was wondering where exactly i can find logs for my ruby script. Where is the output of puts statements.

Not much familiar with Daemons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in an options hash as the second argument to the `Daemons.run` command you can add `:log_output` as true. Like this:

```
Daemons.run('script/meeting_receiver.rb', log_output: true)
```

This will send output to a file titled `meeting_receiver.output`.

See [this example](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons/blob/master/examples/run/ctrl_custom_logfiles.rb) more details.

Comment: I tried above coed, and it is working. But it did not log output all the times on production.

Comment: What was missing from production?